# Python EXscript - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'connect'

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a script working to log into Cisco devices using Python and Exscript.

Being completely new at this I'm stuck with an error I'm getting around the IP address portion.

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'connect'

I get what this means but im not sure how to take an input and make it an object.

```
Switch_IP = raw_input('Core Switch IP :')
print
print "Login Method"
print "============"
print "1.Telnet"
print "2.SSHv2"
print
Connection_Type = raw_input('Connection Type :')
Device_IP = raw_input('IP Address :')

conn = 'null'

if Connection_Type == '1':
    conn = 'Telnet()'
elif Connection_Type == '2':
    conn = 'SSH2()'

account = read_login()                         
conn.connect(Switch_IP)     
conn.login(account)     

conn.execute('term len 0')
conn.execute('term width 0')
conn.execute("show ip arp | i " + Device_IP)

f = open("ARP-Output-tmp.txt","w")
f.write(conn.response)
f.close()
```

It was working at one point but I'm not sure what I've done to stop it working.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set conn equal to one of two strings:

```
if Connection_Type == '1':
    conn = 'Telnet()' 
elif Connection_Type == '2':
    conn = 'SSH2()'
```

So  `'Telnet()'.connect` nor `'SSH2()'.connect` is going to work.

If you have imported SSH or Telnet from somewhere and presuming they are classes then remove the single quotes and you will create an instance which should work once the classes have a connect method.

```
 if Connection_Type == '1':
    conn = Telnet()
elif Connection_Type == '2':
    conn = SSH2()
```

Comment: yes, `conn` is string type variable and string variable do not have `connect` method.

Comment: Thanks guys. Made perfect sense once it was pointed out to me.